# How to limit functions.collect_set in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm dealing with a column of numbers in a large spark DataFrame, and I would like to create a new column that stores an aggregated list of unique numbers that appear in that column.

Basically exactly what functions.collect_set does. However, i only need up to 1000 elements in the aggregated list. Is there any way to pass that parameter somehow to functions.collect_set(), or any other way to get only up to 1000 elements in the aggregated list, without using a UDAF?

Since the column is so large, I'd like to avoid collecting all elements and trimming the list afterwards.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

## Spark 2.4

As pointed out in a comment, [Spark 2.4.0](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) comes with slice standard function which can do this sort of thing.

```
val usage = sql("describe function slice").as[String].collect()(2)
scala> println(usage)
Usage: slice(x, start, length) - Subsets array x starting from index start (array indices start at 1, or starting from the end if start is negative) with the specified length.
```

That gives the following query:

```
val q = input
  .groupBy('key)
  .agg(collect_set('id) as "collect")
  .withColumn("three_only", slice('collect, 1, 3))
scala> q.show(truncate = false)
+---+--------------------------------------+------------+
|key|collect                               |three_only  |
+---+--------------------------------------+------------+
|0  |[0, 15, 30, 45, 5, 20, 35, 10, 25, 40]|[0, 15, 30] |
|1  |[1, 16, 31, 46, 6, 21, 36, 11, 26, 41]|[1, 16, 31] |
|3  |[33, 48, 13, 38, 3, 18, 28, 43, 8, 23]|[33, 48, 13]|
|2  |[12, 27, 37, 2, 17, 32, 42, 7, 22, 47]|[12, 27, 37]|
|4  |[9, 19, 34, 49, 24, 39, 4, 14, 29, 44]|[9, 19, 34] |
+---+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

## Before Spark 2.4

I'd use a UDF that would do what you want after `collect_set` (or `collect_list`) or a much harder UDAF.

Given more experience with UDFs, I'd go with that first. Even though UDFs are not optimized, for this use case it's fine.

```
val limitUDF = udf { (nums: Seq[Long], limit: Int) => nums.take(limit) }
val sample = spark.range(50).withColumn("key", $"id" % 5)

scala> sample.groupBy("key").agg(collect_set("id") as "all").show(false)
+---+--------------------------------------+
|key|all                                   |
+---+--------------------------------------+
|0  |[0, 15, 30, 45, 5, 20, 35, 10, 25, 40]|
|1  |[1, 16, 31, 46, 6, 21, 36, 11, 26, 41]|
|3  |[33, 48, 13, 38, 3, 18, 28, 43, 8, 23]|
|2  |[12, 27, 37, 2, 17, 32, 42, 7, 22, 47]|
|4  |[9, 19, 34, 49, 24, 39, 4, 14, 29, 44]|
+---+--------------------------------------+

scala> sample.
  groupBy("key").
  agg(collect_set("id") as "all").
  withColumn("limit(3)", limitUDF($"all", lit(3))).
  show(false)
+---+--------------------------------------+------------+
|key|all                                   |limit(3)    |
+---+--------------------------------------+------------+
|0  |[0, 15, 30, 45, 5, 20, 35, 10, 25, 40]|[0, 15, 30] |
|1  |[1, 16, 31, 46, 6, 21, 36, 11, 26, 41]|[1, 16, 31] |
|3  |[33, 48, 13, 38, 3, 18, 28, 43, 8, 23]|[33, 48, 13]|
|2  |[12, 27, 37, 2, 17, 32, 42, 7, 22, 47]|[12, 27, 37]|
|4  |[9, 19, 34, 49, 24, 39, 4, 14, 29, 44]|[9, 19, 34] |
+---+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

See [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object (for `udf` function's docs).

Comment: Great question and answer--been looking for the same thing for quite a while, now!  I guess you weren't able to achieve your stated goal of "avoid collecting all elements and trimming the list afterwards"?  I have a LOT of data, so this goal is very important to me.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure I understand. The solutions I propose don't do "collecting" in a traditional driver-based sense. They do "collect_set", but it all happens on executors (which is a good thing).

Comment: sorry, I was thinking of "collect" in a more generic sense.  yes, your solution doesn't collect (in the spark sense), but unless I'm mistaken, it does still collect (in a more general sense) all of the values (as shown in your "all" column) before trimming that list.  Because I have a lot more values, I needed a solution that doesn't do that.  I ended up using the solution below from @user1084563.

Comment: @Mark If you're concerned with memory (due to the number of elements to collect), please note we're talking about descriptions of distributed computations (aka queries) and so their performance might be similar if not the same. Values to trim have all be in a single partition. And access is lazy (using an iterator).

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a modified copy of the collect_set and collect_list functions; because of code scopes, the modified copies must be in the same package path as the originals. The linked code works for Spark 2.1.0; if you are using a prior version, method signatures may be different.

Throw this file (https://gist.github.com/lokkju/06323e88746c85b2ce4de3ea9cdef9bc) into your project as src/main/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expression/collect_limit.scala

use it as:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expression.collect_limit._
df.groupBy('set_col).agg(collect_set_limit('set_col,1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 scala> df.show
    +---+-----+----+--------+
    | C0|   C1|  C2|      C3|
    +---+-----+----+--------+
    | 10| Name|2016| Country|
    | 11|Name1|2016|country1|
    | 10| Name|2016| Country|
    | 10| Name|2016| Country|
    | 12|Name2|2017|Country2|
    +---+-----+----+--------+

scala> df.groupBy("C1").agg(sum("C0"))
res36: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C1: string, sum(C0): bigint]

scala> res36.show
+-----+-------+
|   C1|sum(C0)|
+-----+-------+
|Name1|     11|
|Name2|     12|
| Name|     30|
+-----+-------+

scala> df.limit(2).groupBy("C1").agg(sum("C0"))
    res33: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C1: string, sum(C0): bigint]

    scala> res33.show
    +-----+-------+
    |   C1|sum(C0)|
    +-----+-------+
    | Name|     10|
    |Name1|     11|
    +-----+-------+



    scala> df.groupBy("C1").agg(sum("C0")).limit(2)
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C1: string, sum(C0): bigint]

scala> res2.show
+-----+-------+
|   C1|sum(C0)|
+-----+-------+
|Name1|     11|
|Name2|     12|
+-----+-------+

scala> df.distinct
res8: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C0: int, C1: string, C2: int, C3: string]

scala> res8.show
+---+-----+----+--------+
| C0|   C1|  C2|      C3|
+---+-----+----+--------+
| 11|Name1|2016|country1|
| 10| Name|2016| Country|
| 12|Name2|2017|Country2|
+---+-----+----+--------+

scala> df.dropDuplicates(Array("c1"))
res11: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C0: int, C1: string, C2: int, C3: string]

scala> res11.show
+---+-----+----+--------+                                                       
| C0|   C1|  C2|      C3|
+---+-----+----+--------+
| 11|Name1|2016|country1|
| 12|Name2|2017|Country2|
| 10| Name|2016| Country|
+---+-----+----+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't quite do what i want. If I want up to 1000 distinct values from a column,  "df.limit(1000)" will place a hard upper bound on the number of values returned, but i may be losing distinct values that i should be adding otherwise.

Comment: you have two methods distinct and dropDuplicates that you could execute before the limit, groupby and agg methods. Distinct will look at all columns and droDuplicates allow you to control which columns to compare to identify duplicates. @user1500142

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have mentioned, the performant way of doing this would be to write a UDAF. Unfortunately the UDAF API is actually not as extensible as the aggregate functions that ship with spark. However you can use their internal APIs to build on the internal functions to do what you need.

Here is an implementation for `collect_set_limit` that is mostly a copy past of Spark's internal `CollectSet` AggregateFunction. I would just extend it but its a case class. Really all that's needed is to override update and merge methods to respect a passed in limit:

```
case class CollectSetLimit(
    child: Expression,
    limitExp: Expression,
    mutableAggBufferOffset: Int = 0,
    inputAggBufferOffset: Int = 0) extends Collect[mutable.HashSet[Any]] {

  val limit = limitExp.eval( null ).asInstanceOf[Int]

  def this(child: Expression, limit: Expression) = this(child, limit, 0, 0)

  override def withNewMutableAggBufferOffset(newMutableAggBufferOffset: Int): ImperativeAggregate =
    copy(mutableAggBufferOffset = newMutableAggBufferOffset)

  override def withNewInputAggBufferOffset(newInputAggBufferOffset: Int): ImperativeAggregate =
    copy(inputAggBufferOffset = newInputAggBufferOffset)

  override def createAggregationBuffer(): mutable.HashSet[Any] = mutable.HashSet.empty

  override def update(buffer: mutable.HashSet[Any], input: InternalRow): mutable.HashSet[Any] = {
    if( buffer.size < limit ) super.update(buffer, input)
    else buffer
  }

  override def merge(buffer: mutable.HashSet[Any], other: mutable.HashSet[Any]): mutable.HashSet[Any] = {
    if( buffer.size >= limit ) buffer
    else buffer ++= other.take( limit - buffer.size )
  }

  override def prettyName: String = "collect_set_limit"
}
```

And to actually register it, we can do it through Spark's internal `FunctionRegistry` which takes in the name and the builder which is effectively a function that creates a `CollectSetLimit` using the provided expressions:

```
val collectSetBuilder = (args: Seq[Expression]) => CollectSetLimit( args( 0 ), args( 1 ) )
FunctionRegistry.builtin.registerFunction( "collect_set_limit", collectSetBuilder )
```

Edit:

Turns out adding it to the builtin only works if you haven't created the SparkContext yet as it makes an immutable clone on startup. If you have an existing context then this should work to add it with reflection:

```
val field = classOf[SessionCatalog].getFields.find( _.getName.endsWith( "functionRegistry" ) ).get
field.setAccessible( true )
val inUseRegistry = field.get( SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.sessionState.catalog ).asInstanceOf[FunctionRegistry]
inUseRegistry.registerFunction( "collect_set_limit", collectSetBuilder )
```

Comment: this is a lot cleaner and easier to use than my solution, awesome! (now I'm off to implement this in my existing code...)

Comment: Definitely the best answer here.

Answer (score 1):

use take

```
val firstThousand = rdd.take(1000)
```

Will return the first 1000. 
Collect also has a filter function that can be provided. That would allow you to be more specific as to what is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However,
1) I'd only like a list of _distinct_ values. I see there's an rdd.distinct(), but that doesn't seem to have a limit parameter
2) Not sure how to use a filter function in collect. How would I use a filter to only get a certain number of values?

Comment: Also, ideally I'd like to avoid using rdds. I'm currently something like df.groupBy().agg(<function.collect_set(inputcolumn))). Not sure if it's possible to avoid RDDs but would like to if possible.